# why media query is not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to apply styles on class "search-form" and "range-selector" different for mobile screen and different for large screen. I have used mobile first CSS approach. But its not working. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

This is my html file -

```
<div class="top-container">
    <div class="search-form">
        <form name="flight-search-form" class="flight-search-form">
            <div>
                <label>Flytin from: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Origin City" required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Flytin to: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Destination City" required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Departing: </label>
                <input type="date" placeholder="Departure Date" required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>No of passengers: </label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Passengers" required />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="range-selector">
        <label for="priceRange">
            Price
        </label>
        <input type="range" name="priceRange" min="0" max="10000" step="500" class="price-selector pull-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css file -

```
  .top-container {
     border: 1px solid;
     padding: 10px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }

   .flight-search-form input {
      display: block;
    }

   .search-form {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
   }

   .range-selector {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid;
    }

    .price-selector {
       width: 100%;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
       .search-form {
          width: 60%;
          border: 1px solid;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          float: left;
          color: red;
       }

       .range-selector {
          width: 38%;
          border: 1px solid;
          float: right;
          color: red;
          }
       }
```

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking, because it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n5jjrajx/ (I gave the two elements red background for smaller screens, and blue one for larger, so that it becomes immediately visible.)

Comment: @CBroe its because you are testing in fiddle, try create a page and then run.

Comment: @DanishAdeel: Why would the fact that this is in a fiddle have anything to do with that?

Comment: @CBroe I want to have div having class "search-form" and "range-selector" to display side by side in case of large screens and on separate line in case of mobile screen.  I referred your fiddle. Its working same for both screens.

Comment: The elements _are_ next to each other, if the viewport is wide enough, and below each other if not.

Comment: @CBroe Yes its working for Mozilla browser, but not for chrome. I want to run this on Chrome as well

Comment: I tested the fiddle in Vivaldi, which basically _is_ a Chrome (same rendering engine) – but, if you insist, two screenshots of my fiddle _in Chrome_: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KIOBa.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZBFm.png – so, the same as in Mozilla Firefox … which brings us back to the question, _what the heck are you talking about …?_

Comment: @NehaGupta have you tried my code ?

Answer (score -1):

either use `@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {}`
like [this](http://codepen.io/danishadeel/pen/yOprvy)

or use `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}` and reverse your css code like [this](http://codepen.io/danishadeel/pen/aNExGJ).